Can I set up a Code::Blocks project to set its focus back to the Code::Blocks application after closing the console?
Every time I finish executing a C++ console program, and I press any key to exit, the focus doesn't go back to Code::Blocks' screen.
I'd like to execute a program multiple times by pressing F9, without having to focus the screen again by clicking on it.
I tried moving the other windows around, and I looked into the settings to see if there was any way to configure this behavior, but I wasn't able to find it if it's possible.
How can I set up a Code::Blocks project to set its focus back to the Code::Blocks application after closing the console?
